# Deep residual networks in Resnets

Tags: conv-neural-network, deep-residual-networks

Are the weight matrices of the residual blocks already set to 0 or we need to train the weight matrices of the residual block to be close to 0?
In what cases we backpropagate through the weight matrices of the residual block? And when do we skip backpropagating through them to take the alternate route?

Answer (score 0):

Back propoation happens through both paths, if you have a concat layer that concatenates a block B which is right above it, and a layer A which is cncatenated as residue, gradient to A will come from both the concat layer and the layer after A. Such skip connections are made to counter the vanishing gradients in deep network (the gradient which is backpropogated gets smaller as it passes through more layers)

Comment: So, are the gradients flowing from both the layers(normal connection and skip connection) summed ? or just concatenated?

Comment: There is no meaning to concatenating gradient. You can get more info form [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/268820/gradient-backpropagation-through-resnet-skip-connections) question where it has been discussed previously